# Iteratively add values from C# configuration file to drop down box

Tags: c#, configuration, iteration

I have a configuration file to allow users to select additional values for a drop down box.

```
<add key="confname1" value="localhost" />
<add key="confaddress1" value="127.0.0.1" />
<add key="confname2" value="google" />
<add key="confaddress2" value="8.8.8.8" />
```

I need to first of all iteratively add the values of all the "confname" keys to a drop down list for identification which will later be used to reference their related "confaddress". I've attempted loops utilising something similar to:

```
for (i =1; i < [totalconfigs]; i++)
{
    cbxConfig.Items.Add(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["confname{0}",index])
}
```

The problem I'm running up against is how to create a terminating loop that uses a max value based on the number of available configs (referenced as [totalconfigs] above), since the user can add as many "confname"+"confaddress" pairs as they want to.

Is it possible to create a counter max from the configuration file using something like Configuration.AppSettings.AllKeys with a qualifier to select "confname" which is then used to select the related values?

Comment: Create a custom configuration collection and you can iterate through your configuration settings and make complex types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
var maxIndex = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.AllKeys
                 .ToList()
                 .Where(k => k.StartsWith("confname"))
                 .Count();

for (var index = 1; index <= maxIndex; index++)
{
  cbxConfig.Items.Add(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["confname{0}", index])
}
```

Comment: This is spot on. Thank you. The ToList() function was the real kicker.